# I`m trying to build a 90 degree triangle, with numbers, using only two nested for loops

Tags: javascript

I must draw a 90 degree triangle with numbers, using two nested `for()` loops at most, in plain JavaScript. Now, I've managed to draw the triangle, the only problem is, it`s an iteration from 1 to 9 and on each separate row, I need to have the same number, repeat itself as many times that number! Keep in mind, maximum two nested for loops, no more!

I have stumbled upon solutions for this problem, but they were all using three nested for() loops, instead of two, as I need it to be...

```js
function generatePyramid() {
  var f, k;
  for (f = 1; f <= 9; f++) {
    for (k = 1; k <= f; k++) {
      document.write(k);
    }
    document.write("<br>");
  }
}
generatePyramid();
```

I`m getting:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
```

while I want to have:

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999
```

Comment: `document.write(k);` -> `document.write(f);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one loop :P

```js
for(let i=1; i<=9; i++) document.write( (''+i).repeat(i)+'</br>' );
```

Comment: WOW! Really nice and elegant! :P

Comment: Much better than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

`document.write(k)` needs to be `document.write(f)`. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `repeat()` method.

```js
function generatePyramid() {
        var f, val;

        for (f = 1; f <= 9; f++) {
              val = f.toString().repeat(f);
              document.write(val);
              document.write("<br>");
          }

    }

    generatePyramid();
```